# How to check a polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for convexity.

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\}$,
how do we test if the (interior of the) polygon formed by drawing the line segments  $[{p_{i-1},p_i}]$ for $1\le i \le n$ and also $[p_n,p_1]$ is a convex set in the plane?

Is there a simple algorithm?

Comment: As a first observation, is it true that "if the polygon is NOT convex, there exists a couple of vertices such that the relative segment lies outside the interior of the polygon"?

Comment: Before testing for convexity, you need to test for whether the resulting path is simple (ie no edge intersects any other edge).  If so, then the polygon in question would be the interior face, but if not, it is not clear what set you are referring to as your polygon.

Comment: @Trevor You're right. Perhaps the word "interior" should be in quotes. The path may not be simple. So is there a better algorithm for that than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$? (Since I have $n$ line segments and any two might intersect.)

Comment: Or maybe we just assume this has been checked. Say, by promise it's a simple polygon.

Comment: @amcalde Assuming it is a simple polygon, what is the $\mathcal{O}(n)$ algorithm you have in mind?  I will give one in the answers below.

Comment: No I didn't have one in mind, the $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ I mentioned was for checking each pair of line segments for an intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is $O(n)$. First, define the *deviation* of a vertex $p_r$ to be the (signed) angle by which the direction of $p_rp_{r+1}$ differs from the direction of $p_{r-1}p_r$. This can be calculated as $\arcsin z$, where $z$ is the $z$-coordinate of:

$\dfrac{(p_{r+1}-p_r)}{|p_{r+1}-p_r|} \times \dfrac{(p_r - p_{r-1})}{|p_r - p_{r-1}|}$

Now, we get a convex set if and only if the following two conditions are met:

1. Every deviation has the same sign (or is zero);
2. The sum of the deviations is $\pm 2\pi$.

---

Note that, in practice, the deviation calculations may be ill-conditioned. This will happen if two points are very close together, or two successive edges are nearly parallel. But in these cases, the question of whether the figure is convex is also ill-conditioned.

Also, the sum of the deviations will not be exactly $\pm 2\pi$ in a real-world calculation, because of rounding errors. Instead, you could check that the nearest integer to |sum of deviations|/$2\pi$ is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

It can all be done easily in $O(n)$ operations: for safety, first check that the given polygon can be split in two monotone chains (find the leftmost and rightmost of them and check monotonicity in between, i.e. increasing abscissas); if that fails, the polygon is not convex. Then check that all angles are convex in these chains.

This is a simplified version of [Andrew's algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) for convex hulls. It will also work with non-simple polygons.

Comment: Convex polygons can have acute angles, can't they?

Comment: Ooops, I mean convex angles. (Signed area of $p_{i-1}p_ip_{+1}$ having the right sign over the whole chain.)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to checking oriented area as in Yves Daoust's answer, one could check that the polygon is locally convex at each vertex as follows.

Let $p_i$ be a fixed vertex.  For each other vertex $w$, show that the angles $\angle p_{i-1}p_i w$ and $\angle wp_ip_{i+1}$ are accute.  This can be done arithmetically by using the distances between the points and the law of cosines.  This is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ (maybe?).

Comment: Wait, what about computing the cross product $(p_i - p_{i-1}) \times (p_{i+1}-p_i)$? If I walk along the edge of the polygon and compute that cross product locally, it will give me a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parallel to the $z$-axis, but to be convex it should always have the same sign. Right? I think that would be $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: @amcalde: Almost right. See condition 2 in my answer.